# Is it possible for tick marks on an image to be centered around the -edge- of a pixel?

Tags: image, matlab, plot, center, axis-labels

If I make a 4 pixel by 4 pixel image in Matlab using the image() command, it centers the tick marks in the middle of the pixels. I want the tick marks to be centered on the lower left corner of the pixel. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify x and y coordinates of the pixels and shift them by 0.5:

```
image([0.5,3.5],[0.5,3.5],magic(4))
```

Comment: I tried that before, but it's still missing the tick for 0, and if it was side by side with a regular graph, it doesn't look as nice.

Comment: @Wires: this is strange. In the lower left corner, I get 0 for the x-axis, and 4 for the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
a = randi([0 255], [4 4]);
figure, imagesc(a), caxis([0 255])

b = zeros( size(a)+1 );
b(1:end-1,1:end-1) = a;
figure, pcolor(b), caxis([0 255]), axis ij
```

Note that I extended the matrix `a` because `pcolor` drops the last row/column.

[image: A]
[image: B]

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will do what you want. It places tick marks only at the edges of the pixels:

```
A = ...;  %# Your 4-by-4 matrix
image([0.5 3.5],[0.5 3.5],A);      %# Pixel edges are at 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4
set(gca,'XTick',0:4,'YTick',0:4);  %# Place tick marks at 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4
```